# Creating Login Form Using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, string, visual-studio-2010, authentication

I'm new to Visual Studio 2010 and I'm trying to create a Login form.

I have this code.

```
        OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("host=localhost;usr=root;password=admin;db=timekeeping;");
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM receptionist WHERE username = '" + username_login.ToString() + "' AND password = '" + password_login.ToString() + "';");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.GetString(0) != 1)
            { return false; }
            else
            { return true; }
        }
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
```

There are errors but I don't know what is the problem with that.
Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Hoping that someone ca help me..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Never use string concatenations when building your SQL queries. Use parametrized queries instead:

```
public bool IsValid(string username, string password)
{
    using (var conn = new OdbcConnection("host=localhost;usr=root;password=admin;db=timekeeping;"))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM receptionist WHERE username = @username AND password = @password;";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
        var count = (long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return count > 0;
    }
}
```

and then call like this:

```
bool isValid = IsValid(username_login.ToString(), password_login.ToString());
```

Also if you are using SQL Server you are better with [SqlConenction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) instead of ODBC driver.

Comment: Thank you. I resolved the issue by using your code. However, I wasn't able to check if I input the correct username and password from the database because it seems that it didn't connect with the login button of my form.

Comment: It is stated that I got a problem with the connection. How can I Change ODBC to SqlConnection?

Comment: @schadi, by replacing the `OdbcConnection` with `SqlConnection` and using a proper connection string: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare a string to an int which you are trying here:
`if (reader.GetString(0) != 1)`

You could use GetInt32:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.getint32.aspx

And you shouldn't build your SQL like this but use parameters instead of just constructing a string. You're vulnerable to SQL injection with this way of constructing your SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error message is pretty OdbcDataReader.GetString returns a string not an int. Therefore you can't compare it. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.getstring.aspx)

You probably want to check the length of it? `if (reader.GetString(0).Length != 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace in your code this line

```
if (reader.GetString(0) != 1)
```

with this

```
if (int.Parse(reader.GetString(0)) != 1)
```

Second,

In your userLogin() method you are tryin to return a value whereas the reeturn type is void. Change the return type.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (reader.GetString(0) != "1")            
    { return false; }            
else            
    { return true; }
```

Trying to compare an `int` and a `string` won't really work.
you can also do

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetString(0)) != 1)            
    { return false; }            
else            
    { return true; }
```

However, in some cases this might not work.
And in addition, I'd rather use `GetSqlString` and convert it instead of using `GetString` because I had too many problems with `null`s when I was coding.